# Are SE donations happening this year?

Tags: discussion, moderation, donation

In previous years SE has reached out to moderators, offering to donate money on their behalf to charity.

Is that continuing this year, or has it gone away?

Reference to the process. [Who picks to where Stack Exchanges gives back?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246158/217279)

Comment: I removed the unneeded negativity from this question since it was completely irrelevant to the question and improves the tone such that it is more likely to be answered by the only people that can do so authoritatively: SE employees.

Comment: SE reached out to everyone, was there another process only for moderators?

Comment: The emails have historically gone out in the second week of December. Is there any indication the donations _aren't_ happening this year?

Comment: Would it be possible to link to previous years' posts describing donations?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I updated the question to include a link describing the process.

Comment: I think it should be asked on the Moderator's SO Team IMO.

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFoundMeMonica shouldn't it stay here in the spirit of transparency? That's a big SE talking point nowadays.

Comment: I suspect that quite a few moderators would suggest donating to Monica's GoFundMe. :O

Comment: @MSalters-reinstateMonica That'd likely not be a practical problem, though, since it's a choice of pre-selected options anyway (usually 5).

Answer (score 35):

***Yes!*** the 11th annual [Stack Overflow Gives Back](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=gives+OR+giving+back) is underway and we will be making the same charitable donations as in previous years. There were some scheduling conflicts early on so I'm getting started a bit later than usual, but the emails inviting Moderators to make their charity selections will be going out shortly after the holidays. Have a great New Year!

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 7):

It's on:

[image]

(Interesting side note: I'm not a moderator on Stack Overflow, but the message seems to be coming from that site.)

Comment: Everyone - even mods who don't have SO accounts - have it parented on SO. :)