# Is "Stack Gives Back" for 2019 going to happen?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, moderators, company

Recognizing that I resigned right before the questionnaire should have gone out for Moderators to choose their charity, so I wouldn't have likely been asked to take part; I haven't heard *anything* publicly about the state of "Stack Gives Back".

Robert Cataino [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339693/622284) he was taking it on back in December, but Robert [no longer works at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342079/thank-you-robert-cartaino).

Is it still going to happen for 2019? Or is 2018 (its [ten-year anniversary](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/20/10-years-of-stack-giving-back/)) the last one?

Comment: FWIW: the questionnaire did go out; I helped Robert send it. Given Robert wasn't around to wrap it up... I'm guessing it just got dropped on the floor.

Comment: It bounced from the floor into other hands, but those hands are busy, too.

Comment: I picked this up when Robert left, gonna see where the schedule for the blog post (which is written) landed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are SE donations happening this year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339509/are-se-donations-happening-this-year)

Comment: @JamesJenkins I've edited the question to clarify that, given Robert's departure, it's fair to re-ask whether Stack Gives Back was going to be resumed. Tim's comment and answer both address this correctly, saying that it has been resumed despite Robert initially spearheading it. I think, given that context, it exempts it from being a dupe, but I'm open to being wrong.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Yes. It happened.

The behind-the-scenes of the program is a somewhat complex series of steps, and as you can imagine, there were a number of additional complications to contend with this year. The donations have been made, and a blog post will be going out Saturday or Monday with the usual details. The end results weren't too different from 2018.

As to the question of if your donation was counted, again:

#### Yes. All moderators were counted.

If you filled out the form your donation was made. If you didn't fill out the form but were a moderator on the day the form was closed, a donation was still made on your behalf, just distributed evenly among the charities.

We're sorry for the delays. We know how important this is. Now that the whole process of organizing this has been brought up to date and codified, it won't be a problem going forward.

The [blog post detailing the donations and their recipients has been published](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/09/stack-gives-back-2019/?cb=1).

Comment: [Previous](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/20/10-years-of-stack-giving-back/) [years](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/27/stack-overflow-gives-back-2017/) have also listed some tech foundations which SE Inc donated to. Did those donations also happen this year?

Comment: `Sea Legacy works to bring broad awareness to the problems that face our oceans` Shouldn't that be the problems **faced by** our oceans? I have never heard of oceans taking sides in problems. I know Sea legacy is a real charity, but now the description reads like one made up by the Human Fund. ;p

Comment: @JJforPopcornandMonica Would you believe that got through 4 editors? Will fix in the morning.