# Stack Gives Back 2019 vs 2018

Tags: discussion, moderation, donation

How do the donations for 2019 compare to 2018?

Personally I know that when that message came out this year, I was so disgusted with SE that I did not want any contributions coming from them on my behalf so I did not make a selection.

> Last year, our moderators gave a combined sum of $54,600.00—Wow!
>   That’s $100 x 546 for anyone in the back that missed it, and we’re extremely proud to be part of this with them. But they, our moderators, are the ones that deserve the recognition here; we’re just the stage.  [source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/09/stack-gives-back-2019/)

In money and contributing moderators how do the donations between 2019 and 2018 compare?

**Edit** after learning that SE made donations on my behalf without my consent.  I have posted a feature request, [2020 Donation "Stack Gives Back" Opt out option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344976/217279) and would like to refocus this question to:

**How many moderators made specific donation directions in 2019 compared to 2018?**

Comment: Just FYI, SE still made donations on behalf of moderators who didn't fill in the form. Their donations were distributed evenly among the charities (i.e. each charity received $20).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that is interesting, where did you learn this?

Comment: ["*If you didn't fill out the form but were a moderator on the day the form was closed, a donation was still made on your behalf, just distributed evenly among the charities."*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344655/377214).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog FYI - I tried to link to your second comment but as it is link to a link it goes to destination instead of your comment.  So I linked to my question instead.

Answer (score 8):

According to [previous year's blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/20/10-years-of-stack-giving-back/), there were a few more moderators*, so the donated amount last year was a bit higher:

> This month our 577 incredible community moderators selected from five charities to which we will donate $100 on their behalf (that’s $57,000!)

The post also lists the charities and donated amounts to each of them.

*<sub>: active on Stack Exchange; [how many filled out the form isn't publicly known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344655/295232).</sub>

Comment: Either they or I can't multiply two numbers  and get the right answer ... at least the total matches with my expectation ...

Comment: Or maybe 570 out of 577 made directions in the previous year.

Comment: @JamesJenkins All of the moderators were included. I don't know why the total was rounded down, but if you add up the donations for each individual charity, it adds up to the expected $57,700 as the total donated.